# How to find $10^{-1}$ in $\{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12\} \subseteq \mathbb Z_{14}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse

Here is my question:

> 1. Consider the subset $S = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12\}$ in $\mathbb Z_{14}$, with the operations of addition and multiplication in $\mathbb Z_{14}$.
>
>    (a) Show that $S$ has a multiplicative identity: that is, find a specific element $x$ of $S$ for which $x\cdot a = a$ for each element $a \in S$.
>
>    • Make a multiplication table for $S$. Remember that the multiplication is in $\mathbb Z_{14}$. Your table should
>      contain only the elements ${0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}$. Look at the table to find the identity.
>
>    (b) Using the multiplicative identity you found in part (a), what is $10^{−1}$? That is, what element multiplied by $10$ gives your multiplicative identity?

For part (a), I found the answer, $x=8$. For part (b), I am stuck, even though it's probably simple.

So, I need to find where $10X = 1$ in $\mathbb Z_{14}$, correct? But anything in $\mathbb Z_{14}$ multiplies by 10 will be even, and therefore will not be $1$. Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: No, where $10x=8$ in your set. You just found that this $S$ has an identity, and it is 8, not $1$ (which is not in $S$.)

Comment: So your title is a misnomer - you are not trying to find $10^{-1}$ in $\mathbb Z_{14}$, but in $S$.

Comment: You can use the fact that $10$ is equivalent to $-4$ to make the multiplication slightly easier. Then it should be clear what $x$ satisfies $-4x = 8$.

Comment: @Bungo thanks for the tip! Just starting to learn this stuff and that's pretty nifty

Answer (score 3):

You want $10 x = e$ where $e$ is the answer to $(a)$

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I thought it has to = 1

Comment: When talking about algebraic structures in the abstract, that is, not naming a specific set of numbers such as in this problem, we have a habit of using the symbol $1$ as a name for the multiplicative identity. It just happens that in this particular specific set of numbers, the symbol $1$ means something different to us (namely, "a number not in the set"). So the confusion is understandable.